# Bluetooth low energy with android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working with a bbc microbit microcontroller and I have run into some issues trying to collect sensor data from said device with android. I need to read from six different characteristics on two services xyz axes. As this is such a low level device there is no notify characteristic so I need to constantly read from the device to collect the data but I am currently just getting null or incorrect values.

```
 public void setupBluetooth() {

        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceaddress);
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this,false,mGattCallback);

        BluetoothGattService accelService = new BluetoothGattService(Accel_Service_UUID,BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic accelXChar = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(Accel_X_CHAR_UUID,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic accelYChar = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(Accel_Y_CHAR_UUID,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic accelZChar = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(Accel_Z_CHAR_UUID,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);

        accelService.addCharacteristic(accelXChar);
        accelService.addCharacteristic(accelYChar);
        accelService.addCharacteristic(accelZChar);

        //Log.d("scan","chars" +accelService.getCharacteristics());

    }
    //get callbacks when something changes
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback=new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.d("scan","CONNECTED");
                Log.d("scan","gatt device "+gatt.getDevice());
                gatt.discoverServices();

                //BluetoothGattCharacteristic accelXChar = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(Accel_X_CHAR_UUID,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);

               // Log.d("scan","char "+gatt.readCharacteristic(accelXChar));
               // Log.d("scan","serv "+gatt.getServices());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();

                gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(0));



            Log.d("scan","Number of Services "+  services.size());

           /* gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(0));
            gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(1));
            gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(2));
            gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(3));*/


            for(int x = 0;x < 4;x++){
                BluetoothGattService[] serviceArray = new BluetoothGattService[4];
                serviceArray[x] = services.get(x);
                Log.d("scan","service  "+ (x + 1) + " " + serviceArray[x].getUuid());
            }

            UUID uuid;
            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics;
            ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas;
            for (BluetoothGattService gattService : services) {
                gattCharacteristics = gattService.getCharacteristics();
                charas = new ArrayList<>();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
                        gatt.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                    charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
                    uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid();
                    //gattCharacteristic.;
                    //Log.d("scan","describe "+ gattCharacteristic.describeContents());
                    Log.d("scan","uuid "+uuid);

                    //setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);




                    if (uuid.equals(Accel_X_CHAR_UUID)||uuid.equals(Accel_Y_CHAR_UUID)||uuid.equals(Accel_Z_CHAR_UUID)) {
                        Log.d("scan","value of char  " + gattCharacteristic.getValue().toString());


                    }
                }
            }
        }





        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);

            Log.d("scan","char read "+characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16,1));
            Log.d("scan","char read "+characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,1));
            Log.d("scan","char read "+characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,1));

            //Log.d("scan","char read "+characteristic.getValue());
            byte[] bytes = characteristic.getValue();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
            Log.d("scan","char read "+buffer.getFloat());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);

            Log.d("scan","char changed "+characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16,0));



            Log.d("scan", "char changed"+ characteristic.getValue());


        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement '.. such a low level device there is no notify characteristic ..' is NOT true.

Do check out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le

```
private BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt;
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
boolean enabled;
...
bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
...
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
        UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I get an error when I try to use this line `UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));` Cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: Also, This device has no descriptor option for each characteristic. Looking at it in BLE scanner there is only a read option and the spec sheet says the same so I guess I will just have to drop this idea for a project and start another.

Comment: You're supposed to replace the `SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG` with a value from your device.

Comment: For notification properties, typically comes with UUID 0x2902 descriptor. Put it this way, if the 'BLE scanner' can do notifications with your device, then your app should also be able to do it. Perhaps you are looking at the wrong characteristic.

Comment: BLE scanner cannot do notifications it can only read values. I can't seem to get my application to function properly as I just get null values when I read from the chars. Does android need to have notifications enabled on a char or is there a way to constantly read from the chars and just use the onCharRead callback function?

Comment: I don't understand this statement 'BLE scanner cannot do notifications it can only read values'. By enabling notification, the device will send you the data automatically without you having to request for it manually. This 'notification' feature, of course, depends on the firmware in the device (in your case, the BBC microbit).

In 'BLE scanner', click on the 'N' next to the characteristic you want to monitor, and observe the values changes real time. Of course you need to locate the 'correct' characteristic.

Comment: The disadvantage of 'BLE scanner' is that it does not have a 'label' for the characteristic, so it is trial and error to enable the correct 'N'. You could try 'nRF Connect', which have this 'label' for the characteristic, so it is much more user-friendly.

Comment: There is no notification feature for these characteristics is what I mean. There is no option to "observe the values changes real time". I can only read hex values from the microbit in BLE scanner by pressing the R button constantly and I was trying to apply the same standing within an application. Thanks for your continued help but I have decided to end this project and restart my final year project.

Comment: I see. The problem is on the microbit's firmware that does not have this notification feature. Then of course you can't enable it from the Android side, and it's not Android that does not support it. Anyway, no problem. Best of luck to your final year project.